# How to test if Canvas.toBlob() failed

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Using `canvas.toBlob(callback, ...)`, I am converting several large canvas elements (2048x2048 pixels) to png.

However, at least in Chrome, the callback is not always called. There are no errors generated in Chrome Devtools.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there are way to check if `toBlob()` failed, aside from timing out after *x* seconds?
2. Under which conditions does `toBlob()` fail? How do I know which condition was not met / How do I get an error message?

---

The code I am using:

```
function trigger_browser_download(blob, fileName) { "use strict";
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};

function download_canvas(canvas, filename) { "use strict";
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        debugger; // not always reached
        if(blob instanceof Blob) {
            trigger_browser_download(blob, filename);
        } else {
            console.error("error generating blob");
        }
    }, 'application/octet-binary'); 
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = 2048;
    canvas.width = 2048;
    download_canvas(canvas, i + ".png");

}
```

Comment: Really hard to tell. Does it also happen when you don't force the MIME Type? Usually what could make it fail are wrong parameters, and tainted canvas, in both cases, an error would be thrown at call of toBlob.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your suggestion. Removing the MIME type did not help. After some investigation I suspect its a bug in Chrome: there seems to be a connection between toBlob, the debugger and the event loop. The problem occurs when a breakpoint is set next to `download_canvas`. It does not occur when the call to `download_canvas` is immediately followed by a return statement...

Comment: @Kaiido You could post the rest of your comment as an answer as you are answering question 2 from above.